# Develop with SQLite on mac and run on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, macos, sqlite

I'm very new to using C# and .Net on MAC so:

I need to develop a desktop application using either WinForms or WPF with a local database that will not nee any installation, just run the ".exe" file and use the program.

I have a new MAC laptop that runs smooth and an old Windows laptop that takes an hour to load.
So trying to work with the Windows laptop drove me crazy and I've decided to try and compile all the DAL and BL projects on my MAC and have only the UI on the Windows laptop.

I can't work with Microsoft Access as a database on my MAC so I thought I'll use SQLite instead (Still don't know if it's a good idea).

The thing is:

1. Are there .dll files of SQLite for MAC?
2. If I compile the DAL and BL projects on my MAC will would I be able to use their .dll files on the UI project in the Windows laptop? Or would I need to copy the projects and replace the SQLite .dll files for Windows?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Fyi Microsoft Access is not a database.

Comment: SQLite is _included with_ MacOS, in `/usr/bin`

Comment: @Rabban, I meant Microsoft Office Access.

Comment: @stuartd, can you please post a code sample how to reference and use SQLite in a C# project on MAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this link to use [SQLite Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/sqlite/).

Also here is a great tutorial to get started with SQLite: [SQLite tutorials](http://sqlitetutorials.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If your target platform is Windows, you maybe could consider using Windows and Visual Studio via Bootcamp or VM on your Mac. Sqlite can be integrated by nuget package.

Comment: VM is not so comfortable to use, I've tried Parallels.